# String value shifting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, patindex

Not sure how to clearly describe what I'd like to achieve, hope my question below does make some sense.

Let's suppose I have the string `ABCDE`. I would like to iterate as many times as its length to create shifted patterns of the string as depicted below

`_BCDE`,`A_CDE`,`AB_DE`,`ABC_E`,`ABCD_`

So I would like to create all the combinations with an underscore in all possible positions in order to use them in a query like

```
DECLARE @WORD AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @WORD = 'ABCDE'
SELECT position = PATINDEX(CONCAT('%', @WORD, '%'), 'BGHKAGCDEBABIDEKFABCREDNBSALCDEOPL');
```

where @WORD should be the words with the `_`.

I have the feeling that this can be done using a recursive `CTE` but I'm not sure how to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @WORD AS NVARCHAR(50);
SET @WORD = 'ABCDE';

with cte as (
      select 1 as n, @word as word
      union all
      select n + 1, word
      from cte
      where n < len(word)
     )
select word, stuff(word, n, 1, '_')
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=586a20f060f081fd74818e9f68cdd7fc) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt without using a `Recursive CTE`. Handle with care when dealing with large sized strings though, because `replicate` has its [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
with cte1 as (select 'abcde' as txt)

select value, stuff(value, row_number() over (order by value), 1, '_') as permutations
from cte1
cross apply string_split(replicate(txt+'.',len(txt+'.')-1),'.')
where value<>'';
```

**Outputs**

```
value   permutations
abcde   _bcde
abcde   a_cde
abcde   ab_de
abcde   abc_e
abcde   abcd_
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5688629433896bd8bcff60cb901a6c1e)**